# use stdlib functions with indexing instead of Iterators?

Tags: c++, indexing, iterator, eigen

I want to use [std::partial_sum](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sum) on [Eigen::VectorXd](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__matrixtypedefs.html#ga8554c6170729f01c7572574837ecf618) but I couldn't really find Iterators in Eigen data structures at all. Is there some sort of quick Iterator wrapper that uses classic indexing under the hood? Or what would be a good way to do this instead of re-implementing partial sum with indexing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always get the raw pointer to your data and use it in conjunction with the size.

```
std::partial_sum(array.data(), array.data() + array.rows() * array.cols(), output.data());
```

There are 2D iterators available in Eigen though, if you want to iterate over one dimension first and then the other one for each element.

Comment: mmh yeah I just now came across Eigens Map function. But that's the other way around :)

Comment: Yes indeed. I'm using this intensively in my code ;)

Answer (score 2):

This has been implemented in October 2018, and will be part of the 3.4 release. You can already use them with the trunk version, e.g.,

```
void foo(Eigen::VectorXd& in_out)
{
    std::partial_sum(in_out.begin(), in_out.end(), in_out.begin());
}
```

Godbolt demonstration (showing near equivalent code to `std::vector`): https://godbolt.org/z/bFxcCA

See this (merged) pull request, if you are interested in details: https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/pull-requests/519/